# ngCordova saving Photo to Gallery

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

Using http://ngcordova.com/ I'm having trouble trying to save the photo into the gallery on Android.

Initially the file wasn't passing the image data back after taking the picture when using the following options ;

```
var options = {
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    correctOrientation: true,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true
};
```

I found that to fix this I had to downgrade the camera plugin from 0.3.6 to 0.3.5 thanks to [forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/having-problem-with-ngcordova-camera-plugin/19562/4).

The routine that saves is as follows ;

```
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imagePath) {
  var currentName = imagePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
  var d = new Date(),
  n = d.getTime(),
  newFileName = n + ".jpg";

  //Move the file to permanent storage
  $cordovaFile.moveFile(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, currentName, cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + "DCIM/Camera", newFileName).then(function(success){
        //sucess

        }, function(error){
          //an error occured
          //Booooooo
        });
```

I don't want to hard code paths but was just testing to see if I could get the photo in the correct directory. I had tried the directories from this [post](http://www.joshmorony.com/store-camera-photos-permanently-using-phonegap-ionic-ngcordova/).

I found on my Nexus 5 though the cordova.file.tempDirectory was always null.

Is it a bug with the camera plugin for saving to Gallery or is it not just implemented correctly yet for Android.

Cheers for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to hardcoded the `cache` directory.

you can know the cache directory from `imagePath`

just remove the filename, and you will get the `cache` directory, where the camera plugin save your photos before you move it to `external` directory as you want

*I'va tested it, and in my case, the `cache` directory is
`file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my-app-id/cache`